# Visual C# Dataset to Class

Tags: c#, database, class, dataset

I am a student programer working in Visual Studios C# and I am trying to access information from my dataset and insert the data into a class. This is not, by any means, homework I've just have some personal projects I've been wanting to try. I have tried several approaches that have been mentioned on this site; however, no information is displayed. My code looks similar to this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string ColumnData1
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public int ColumnData2
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string Display()
    {
        string MyString = ColumnData1 + ColumnData2.ToString();
        return MyString;
    }
}
```

I use this to insert data into class:

```
private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyDataSet.MyDataTable MDT = new MyDataSet.MyDataTable();

    List<MyClass> MyList = new List<MyClass>();

    foreach (DataRow MyDataRow in MDT.Rows)
    {
        Mylist.Add(new MyClass()
                   {
                       ColumnData1 = (string)MyDataRow["Data1"],
                       ColumnData2 = (int)MyDataRow["Data2"]
                   {
    }
```

Lastly to display the information:

```
    textBox1.Text = Mylist[0].Display();
}
```

In the end, however, nothing ends up displaying. This also wasn't the only thing I've tried to display the information.. it's like the information doesn't exist. I don't receive any errors and when I try to add a "Stop Point" at the insertion part of the code it just skips it. I should mention also that I have many text boxes and list boxes that pull data off the database just fine, of course Visual Studios binds those for me. Any help is very much appreciated.

Edit:
Ok, excluding the new data table. If I had an existing dataset how would I would I use it to fill my class.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're loading the data table with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal because `your DataTable is empty` (Your create instance)

```
MyDataSet.MyDataTable MDT = new MyDataSet.MyDataTable();//<------Empty


foreach (DataRow MyDataRow in MDT.Rows)
{
  ....
}
```

Fill DataSet :

```
string queryString = 
  "SELECT .... FROM YourTable";
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);

DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(dataSet, "NameOfDataSet");
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but when you add a dataset to a project doesn't it set up all access information and everything?

Comment: Kiko it's not problem, because dataset stay just data structure , you must populate your dataset (with for example sql adapter) and in the second time use foreach in order to parse

Comment: Would you mind showing me an example of how to do that please? Or maybe point me to some reading material that might? Please and thank you.

Comment: I'am happy to help you Kiko, read this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You must have some data in MDT before you insert it in the MyList, List of MyClass.

Declaration without data:

```
MyDataSet.MyDataTable MDT = new MyDataSet.MyDataTable();
```